# react-native authentification app using AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

developers 
I'm working on a React Native project created with Expo
i use * AsyncStorage *to make a user authentication 
i faced this problem when i use my phone to test my app
[this is a capture of the error in my phone, but there is not erreur in * Expo DevTools console *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltEXb.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about the Expo but since React native 0.60, Facebook removed some of these packages from the react native core to reduce the size because those libs are not necessary for all the users. So in order to use AsyncStorage, now you have to manually install it using NPM or Yarn first. So from your screenshot I assume that is true for Expo as well.

However do the following and you will be fine. I assume you have react native version higher than 0.60

if your package manager is Yarn, then : `yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage`

or

if your package manager is NPM, then : `npm i --save @react-native-community/async-storage`

After that, use below code part to update iOS Pods. Run this from your project root using terminal.

`cd ios / && pod install && cd ...`

Now try to run the app. App will start to work if there are no any other issues.
For more information about AsynStorage, please use [this link](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage).